# How can I make a class raw pointer to TUniquePtr?

Tags: c++, casting, unreal-engine4

In C++ you can do this to make a Unique pointer have the same data that a raw pointer has, it's an example for what I aim to do in Unreal Engine

```
class Test
{
public:
    int num = 10;
};

int main()
{
    Test* p_test = new Test();
    unique_ptr<Test> p_unique_test = make_unique<Test>(*p_test);
    cout << p_unique_test.get()->num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing in Unreal is to make a single static data table creator class Unique pointer where is located the .csv file data which contains the path for meshes, `sfx, vfx,` etc and it will be created only one time and be accessed from many classes to create game resources, but I am having issues that it Unreal can't cast the pointer, how could be this done?
It throws me the error C2248: 'TUniquePtr<AData_table_manager,TDefaultDelete>::TUniquePtr': cannot access private member declared in class 'TUniquePtr<AData_table_manager,TDefaultDelete>'

The header file

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Engine/DataTable.h"
#include "Data_table_manager.generated.h"
#define MAX_WEAPON_COUNT 6

// Fs_weapon_data
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct Fs_weapon_data : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

        UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FString type = "";

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FString mesh_path = "";

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FString audio_path = "";

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FString bullet_mesh_path = "";

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FString mag_mesh_path = "";

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FVector collider_size = FVector::ZeroVector;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        FVector collider_pos = FVector::ZeroVector;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        int     current_ammunition_count = 0;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        int     max_bullet_count = 0;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Weapon_data_variable)
        int     damage = 0;

    FString UI_material_bp_path = "";
    FString bullet_bp_path = "";
    int     current_bullet_count = 0;
};

UCLASS()
class PUBG_UE4_API AData_table_manager : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
private:
    static TUniquePtr<AData_table_manager> p_data_table;

    // 
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    class UDataTable* mp_weapon_data_table;
    Fs_weapon_data    m_weapon_data_arr[MAX_WEAPON_COUNT];
    int               m_current_weapon_count = 0;

    // 
    const FString     mk_weapon_mesh_path       = "/Game/Items/FPS_Weapon_Bundle/Meshes/";
    const FString     mk_bullet_bp_path         = "/Game/Blueprints/Weapon/Ammo/BP_";
    const FString     mk_rendertarget_mesh_path = "/Game/Materials/Weapon_UI/UI_material_";
    const FString     mk_sound_path             = "/Game/SFX/Gun_sounds/";

public:

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = Sound)
        USoundBase* p_empty_ammo_sound = nullptr;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = Sound)
        USoundBase* p_shot_sound_arr[MAX_WEAPON_COUNT];

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = Sound)
        USoundBase* p_reload_sound = nullptr;

public:
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AData_table_manager();

    static void Init_data_table_pointer();

    static auto Get_ptr() { return p_data_table.Get(); }

public:
    Fs_weapon_data Get_weapon_data(int _index) { return m_weapon_data_arr[_index]; }

};
```

And the `cpp` file

```
    void AData_table_manager::Init_data_table_pointer()
{
    static ConstructorHelpers::FClassFinder<AActor> DATA_TABLE_MANAGER(TEXT("Blueprint'/Game/Blueprints/BP_Data_table_manager.BP_Data_table_manager_C'"));
    AData_table_manager* tmp_p_data_table_manager;
    
    if (DATA_TABLE_MANAGER.Succeeded())
    {
        tmp_p_data_table_manager = Cast< AData_table_manager>(DATA_TABLE_MANAGER.Class);
        p_data_table             = MakeUnique<AData_table_manager>(MoveTemp(tmp_p_data_table_manager));
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all note that `make_unique<Test>(*p_test)` *copies* the object that `p_test` is pointing to. You now have two different and distinct objects, that are unrelated to each other. Secondly, you don't need `get` to use the object, `p_unique_test->num` will work just fine.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include more details about the "issues" you have. Do you get build errors? Crashes at run-time? Unexpected results? Something else? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Ok edited it, it throws the error C2248: 'TUniquePtr<AData_table_manager,TDefaultDelete<T>>::TUniquePtr': cannot access private member declared in class 'TUniquePtr<AData_table_manager,TDefaultDelete<T>>

Comment: @Game_dev That error doesn't come from the first code block does it? Can you post a minimal reproducible example? Are you using `std::make_unique` correctly?

Comment: No @Offtkp the first block is an example which what I am doing, the issue that I am having is from the second block.

Comment: Regarding your first code block: Using `new` completely defeats the purpose of smart pointers. Instead of `Test* p_test = new Test(); unique_ptr<Test> p_unique_test = make_unique<Test>(*p_test);` use `unique_ptr<Test> p_unique_test = make_unique<Test>();`. `make_unique` calls the constructor of `Test` with the arguments you give in the brackets.

Comment: @OliL thanks gotta keep in mind